# How can I cd to a class/object in a .pryrc file?

Tags: ruby, pry

I want the .pryrc for a particular project to cd to a class context that will be the context for 99% of all pry sessions in that project.

just doing:

```
cd MyModule
```

doesn't work:

```
Error loading ./.pryrc: undefined method `cd' for main:Object
```

which is confusing because methods defined in the .pryrc are in the pry session context.

```
Pry.cd MyModule
```

also doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we will add better support for this in the future, but in the meantime put this in your `.pryrc`:

`Pry.config.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, :set_context) { |_, _, pry| pry.input = StringIO.new("cd MyModule") }`

If you would like to see better support for this feature in the future, please [file an issue](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues)